# Кастомные ключи в словаре

Tags: python, хеширование

Как известно, в питоне в качестве ключа для словаря может выступать хешируемый объект. По-хорошему, как я понял, хеш не должен изменяться, но всё же.

Решил поэкспериментировать и создать свой класс, который наследуется от **list** и у которого определён метод **__hash__**.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}{list(self)}'
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}{list(self)}'
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))
```

После чего создал словарь с ключом в виде объекта **MyList** и попытался обратиться к этому ключу:

```
ml = MyList([1, 2, 3])
d = {ml: 'value'}
print(d)
print(d[ml])

>>>{MyList[1, 2, 3]: 'value'}
>>>value
```

Изменил список и вновь попытался обратиться к значению по ключу:

```
ml.append(4)
print(d)
>>>{MyList[1, 2, 3, 4]: 'value'}

print(d[ml])
>>>KeyError: MyList[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Я подумал, что данное поведение ожидаемо, т.к. хеш объекта изменился. Но запустив n-ое количество раз подряд данный скрипт, то он может отработать без ошибки несколько раз.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему так происходит?

**PS**
Если в методе **__hash__** использовать функцию **id** вместо **hash**, то скрипт будет гарантировано выполняться:

```
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(str(self))

ml = MyList([1, 2, 3])
h1 = hash(ml)
d = {ml: 'value'}
print(d[ml])
ml.append(4)
h2 = hash(ml)
print(d[ml])
print(h1 == h2)

>>>value
>>>value
>>>False
```

Хотел бы разобраться в питоновской магии (а может и не магии и это всё логически объясняется).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, насколько актуально это для словарей сейчас, но раньше механика была такая:

1. Хэш используется для определения того, в какую ячейку хэш-таблицы попадёт элемент.
2. Количество ячеек ГОРАЗДО меньше, чем количество возможных хэшей. Поэтому разные хэши могут соответствовать одной ячейке.
3. Окончательное сравнение всё равно идёт по значению.

Поэтому у вас в одних запусках разные хэши попадали в одну ячейку, а так как значение совпадает, то элемент находился. А в других запусках хэши попадали в разные ячейки и до этапа сравнения значений дело просто не доходило.

А чтобы такой "магии" не получалось - хэш всегда должен быть одинаковый для одного объекта (например, id - с этой точки зрения вполне хороший хэш).